# Relative import error using python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, module

I'm using the built-in python unittest module. My directory structure is as follows:

```
game.py
test/test_game.py
```

The content of test_game.py:

```
import unittest
from ..game import *

class TestGame(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_pawn(self):
        game = Game()
        game.make_move("e2e3")

        self.assertEqual(game.board[6][5].piece_type, "P")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here's the problem.  When I run `python -m unittest test/test_game.py`  I get the error:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_game
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.test_game'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `test/__init__.py` file.  With this change, I didn't even need the relative `..game` import.. But I'm wondering why python requires this just to import